# How to apply multiple column filter(String) in python

Tags: python, regex, filter

I would like to apply mutiply keyword filter for filtering down on columns.I tried this code:

```
df = df.filter(regex='AMP','amp','date')
```

Error I get :

```
df = df.filter(regex='AMP','amp','date')
                                ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument.
```

Basically,I want all the columns with these keywords contained in their column name.
Thank you in advance

Comment: error message says: never use positional erguments behind keyword arguments in python - simply because position is meaningless after an arbitrary list of kwargs is provided

Comment: basically `df = df.filter('AMP','amp','date')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex has to be one valid regex string. You separated three strings by comma, so python interpreted the last two strings as separate arguments (without keyword). the proper 'or' - operator in regex is '|', so your desired filter would look like this:

```
df.filter(regex='AMP|amp|date')
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked!